# Finding the vth moment of a distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Given the distribution
$$n(r) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}rln\sigma_g}exp^{\frac{-ln^2(r/r_g)}{2ln^2(\sigma_g)}}$$
Where $r$&$r_g$ have the same physical units and $\sigma_g$ is a dimensionless parameter. My task is to find the $v^{th}$ moment by definition.

So far, I think my integration limits are from $0$ to $\infty$. Furthermore, I think a change of variable could be used such that $x = ln(\frac{r}{r_g})$. However, even with the change in variable, it seems to leave two variables in the integration - thus I'm not sure whether to treat r like a constant once we replace with $dx$. Here's my work so far:
$$E(r^v) = \int_{0}^{\infty}(r^v*\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}rln\sigma_g}e^{\frac{-ln^2(r/r_g)}{2ln^2(\sigma_g)}}) dr$$
$$x = ln(r/r_g)$$
$$rdx = dr$$
$$E(r^v) = \int_{0}^{\infty}(r^v*\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}rln\sigma_g}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2ln^2(\sigma_g)}}) dx * (r)$$
$$E(r^v) = \int_{0}^{\infty}(r^v*\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}ln\sigma_g}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2ln^2(\sigma_g)}})dx$$
$$E(r^v) =r^v*\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}rln\sigma_g} \int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{\frac{-x^2}{2ln^2(\sigma_g)}}) dx$$

I'm stumped and need help solving this integral. Much thanks!

Comment: This is actually the log-normal PDF I believe. While there are a lot of easier ways to solve for the $v^{th}$ moment, we are supposed to do it by definition

Comment: As hinted above, match the parameters in the given pdf with $\mu, \sigma$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution . Next it just boils down to find out the mgf of standard normal as $E[R^v] = E[e^{v\sigma Z + v\mu}]$

Comment: Is there a way I can just leverage it for the last part of the integral (as I wrote in the last step?) Its something I found out, but I can't really take advantage of because its supposed to be done by definition if that makes sense.

Comment: At the end they are the same - if you force yourself to stick to this integral, you are actually transforming it back to an integral with normal pdf inside. So it will be best to avoid integral here and use the existing result if you are allowed to do so. For your integral, an obvious mistake is you forget to transform the variable $r$ to $x$, and you pulled $r^v$ out of the integral after transformation.

Comment: How do you transform $r^v$?

Comment: @BGM how do you also transform the variable r to x?

Comment: The transformation is stated by you - $x = \ln \frac {r} {r_g} \Rightarrow r = r_g e^x$

Comment: @BGM should you use that to replace $r^v$?

Comment: every $r$ inside the integrand need to be transformed in the same way - there is no exception.

Answer (score 4):

The last integral can be solved by taking a change of variable $t=\frac{x^2}{2\ln^2\sigma_g}$ and then using the gamma function to solve it, being: $dx=x^{-1}\ln^2{\sigma_g}dt$ and $x=\sqrt{2}\ln{\sigma_g}\sqrt t$, the integral takes the next form:

$\int_0^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2\ln^2\sigma_g}}dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\ln^2\sigma_g}{\sqrt 2\ln\sigma_g}t^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-t}dt=\frac{\ln\sigma_g}{\sqrt 2}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\sqrt \pi\ln\sigma_g}{\sqrt 2}$

So you just substitute this for your integral in the last step and get the final result.

However, I am not sure if you are doing the integration correctly, as you are taking the $r$ variable outside the integral after the change of variable, but those $r$ are variables that depend on $x$, and so you cannot take them out of the integral. You should write all in terms of $x$ so that you can solve for x.